# Difference between closing FileInputStream and setting it to null

Tags: null, garbage-collection, fileinputstream

In Java, when we close a resource like a Connection, a FileInputStream, a FileOutputStream, how is it different than setting these object instances to null? i.e in both scenarios, these objects are eligible for garbage collection. So what is the purpose of providing the `close` method with these classes?

Comment: one of the many online tutorials/articles would answer this.

Comment: `#close()` isn't about garbage collection. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html#close()

Comment: I guess, if you don't close it, then if you try to write to open again before GC, then you might not be able to open it until GC occurs because OS thinks that file is opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `close` method of IO classes is usually there to execute cleanup tasks, e.g. closing file handlers, flushing and closing sockets. These cleanup tasks are not related purely to allocation and GC itself cannot handle them.

Further, **setting a reference** to `null` to explicitly declare that the object will no longer be used is **not a recommended coding practice**. The GC will automatically handle the cases when the object is no longer accessible. Explicit `null` setting will only clutter your source code.